# redirecting domain to nameservers in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have configured my domain to heroku IPs
75.101.163.44
75.101.145.87
174.129.212.2

But it's not redirecting my app to my domain. The error says

**There is no app configured at that hostname.
Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL.**

Does each Heroku app have its own IP address? If so how to get the unique IP and how to redirect it to domain. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just follow [these instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) and use the (unfortunately no longer free) Zerigo DNS Add-On. It's pretty easy.

Heroku applications don't have a static IP address because they're distributed across nodes in Heroku's dyno grid.

Comment: Heroku applications, by default, don't have static IP addresses because they're distributed across Amazon EC2 instances, which by default don't have static IP addresses. However, if you select the Custom SSL addon, Heroku will reserve an EC2 instance with a static IP address and place your app on that EC2 instance.

Answer (score 8):

After following these instructions:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains
You can point your DNS servers to Heroku via the following method:

1. Say you are using something like Gandi.net (or GoDaddy, BlueHost, etc. they should all have similar components). Go to your Gandi console and go to your domain You want to create a new *zone file*, since you can't edit a zone file that your domain is already using. So clone an existing zone file and click to edit it, if need be.
2. In the record with name:www and type: CNAME, change the Value to **[yourherokuapp].herokuapp.com**, whereby [yourherokuapp] is given to you after you do a *git push heroku master* or *heroku create*
3. Delete the record with name:@ and type: A
4. Add three entries:

   - Name:@, type: A, address/value: 75.101.163.44
   - Name:@, type: A, address/value: 75.101.145.87
   - Name:@, type: A, address/value: 174.129.212.2

Which are Heroku DNS addresses.

And that's that. Wait a few hours (or however long the TTL is), and check

```
host www.your_domain.com
```

from the shell to see what address it responds to.

Comment: but this does only works with "www.domain.com" not "domain.com, isn't?

Comment: This answer used to be correct but is now outdated. You do not need the A types she listed. Follow these directions precisely (switch strikingly out for heroku): http://support.strikingly.com/knowledgebase/articles/331752-gandi-domains

Comment: This does still work, though not officially supported, as of May 2020.