# Heroku and Zerigo Setup Issue

Tags: heroku

**EDIT2: Waiting to see if my changes were successful.**

---

EDIT: I reinstalled everything using the command line Zerigo install command (the original question was for manual setup). THe problem now: the custom domains I set up do not work properly. Visiting the custom domain simply returns an error in Chrome: "Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.myapp.com" even though the custom domain I added was "www.myapp.com?

---

I've been trying to set up a custom domain on my Cedar Heroku app by following instructions at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/zerigo_dns.

In the tutorial for setting up a domain on Zerigo, one of the instructions for adding a host is to add the IP address of the webserver. How do I go about finding this information? I'm having trouble finding any resource that helps me with this.

Am I supposed to be adding the IP address of my app at **_**.herokuapp.com? When I try to do a look up of this address, I never get a consistent address (probably because of Heroku's many servers). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Heroku should completely handle adding the correct records to Zerigo. Are you setting up Zerigo manually or did you use `heroku addons:add zerigo_dns:basic`?

Comment: That's not the original way I had it set up. I added a domain and then added the Zerigo addon via the Heroku addon web interface. I went ahead and removed everything (domains, addon) and installed the Zerigo addon with the command. Then I added a custom domain but the custom domains don't work - in Google Chrome I just get a message saying "Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.myapp.com"

Comment: Depending on your DNS settings it can take anywhere from 1 hour to 72 hours for changes to propagate. How long ago did you change your name servers for your domain?

Comment: With the most recent changes I made I guess it was about 5 minutes ago when I set up everything. So it's basically a waiting issue from here on out? The Heroku page on Zerigo DNS (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/zerigo_dns) says that I can verify my DNS settings with 'dig ns yourdomain.com'. Is this something that is propagated immediately?

Comment: No, always takes a while. Just verify your registrar has the correct settings for Zerigo's name servers in their web control panel. If it does, try `dig`. When `dig` reflects what the web control panel says, then it's propagated (at least for you). By then, if Heroku is set up correctly it should work.

Comment: Cool thanks for the help! Will report back in a couple of days!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linking Zerigo and Heroku is a three step process.

(1) Use the `heroku addons:add zerigo_dns:basic` command or add Zerio manually through the add-ons page on your Heroku app.

(2) With your registrar or hosting provider to have the domain resolve properly. For Zerigo add all nameservers:

a.ns.zerigo.net

b.ns.zerigo.net

e.ns.zerigo.net

c.ns.zerigo.net

d.ns.zerigo.net

(3) And this is the step I think you may be missing. Log into Zerigo either through your Heroku configuration panel under "add-ons" or log into Zerigo directly. Select the DNS tab next to Account and Servers. On the left panel select the domain you have resolving to Zerigo: this domain will appear. Within this domain under "Nameservers" next to "Hosts" click "Add Snippet". Add both the recommended snippets proxy.heroku.com and the redirect record that excludes the www.

Wait the TTL period (usually 15 minutes) and your domains will work as expected.

Comment: The step I'm actually missing is (2). I don't have my app registered with a specific registrar or hosting provider other than Heroku. Does that mean I won't be able to get custom domains working? I was under the impression that with Heroku and Zerigo, those were the only tools I needed.

Comment: You do not need step 2 to get custom domains working. Step 2 is if you want a non herokuapp.com URL to resolve (a custom domain). If you want something other than herokuapp.com you need to purchase a domain and set its name servers to your DNS provider (2). If you want subdomains a la something.herokuapp.com make sure you are creating a separate DNS record for each subdomain.

Lastly if you are not using a custom domain name you do not need to set up name servers separately just follow the instructions.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539701/redirecting-domain-to-nameservers-in-heroku