# Unable to configure Zerigo with Heroku

Tags: heroku, zerigo

I have added the Zerigo add-on with heroku. I have followed the steps in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966407/heroku-and-zerigo-setup-issue).

Except for the third step. When I attempted to do that, I got an info message that I don't need to do that if I am using the add-on in heroku.

However, if I try to access my custom domain, I get an application error. Executing the command

`$ heroku logs`

I get the following output (pasted partially):

```
at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET
```

I went through [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h70-access-to-bamboo-http-endpoint-denied) article which says that I need to replace proxy.heroku.com with myapp.herokuapp.com - but I don't understand how I need to do that. I tried adding the snippet as suggested in that stackoverflow answer linked earlier, but in that it points to proxy.herokuapp.com

I got this confirmed when I executed a ping command on my custom domain and got the following output:

```
64 bytes from proxy.heroku.com : icmp_req=68 ttl=46 time=289 ms
```

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Go to https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps
2. Click on the name of your app
3. Click on "Zerigo DNS Zerigo Basic" and click "Configure". You should see your custom domain name listed under "Host Records."
4. Click "Add Snippet". Choose "Heroku" from the dropdown menu.
5. Click "Add Selected Records".
6. **Go to the CNAME entry under host records and click "Edit". Change data from `proxy.heroku.com` to `YOURAPP.herokuapp.com`**

I also had to do the following:

1. Go back to https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps
2. Click on the name of your app
3. Click on Settings
4. Under "Domains" add your custom domains e.g. mydomain.com. I also had to add one starting with "www."

You may have to wait 10-15 min for the settings to propagate.

Comment: I had forgotten to add the domain starting with www

Comment: I'm also having a similar problem. I've followed these instructions and I still get this error (H70) in my logs when I go to mydomain.com.  Moreover, when I use www.mydomain.com, it doesn't resolve at all. I performed a DNS propagation check using https://www.whatsmydns.net/ , and it does seem to resolve to myapp.herokuapp.com. Any ideas on what I could be missing?

Comment: @callmekatootie, where did you add the domain? On zerigo? I have it there as a CNAME and it shows up when I type heroku domains.. I've had this set-up for several hours now, is it possible that it could take this long to propagate?

Comment: i had this problem too and now it is working with "www.domain.com" but does not work with "domain.com". what is wrong with this?

Comment: Two things: 1) When you execute the command `heroku domains` you should see three Domain name: One is myapp.herokuapp.com, second is mycustomdomain.com and third is www.mycustomdomain.com

Comment: Next thing is that Zerigo Add-on incorrectly adds records for Cedar stack. You can delete the records in the Hosts tab of the configuration page of Zerigo and add two records - one with type "Redirect", "host" mycustomdomain.com with data "http://www.mycustomdomain.com" and another record with type "CNAME", "host" www.mycustomdomain.com and "data" "myapp.herokuapp.com" hope this works...

Comment: Thanks @callmekatootie, your comments are inline with what I found. My wwww is working now (maybe took a day to get straight). Original instructions should be good.

Comment: I'm still having the problem.  www.mysite.herokuapp.com routes properly (no problems) but mysite.herokuapp.com does not (I keep getting the h70 error).  I've gone through all the suggestions above and am not sure what else i can do.  I've configured a couple other sites before and they are all working -AND, the configs look similar so nothing jumps out at me as being wrong... my site is snowbirdhosts.com  and the heroku site is mthost2.herokuapp.com  in case that helps

Comment: @Allen Maxwell, having the same issue. My solution was to redirect mysite.com to www.mysite.com with a redirect record in zerigo. Not always the best way to go, but it's a quick solve if you're looking for one

Comment: @hananamar, thx for the idea but it didn't work for me.  i haven't had much time to spend on this since the initial problem - just need to get to it later i guess.  not sure why it's not working...

Answer (score 2):

If the error is ..

```
Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied"
```

Change your `CNAME` entry ..

```
yourdomain.heroku.com -> yourdomain.herokuapp.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible is IT working, but you need to flush your DNS cache on your machine? That's a commmon problem, that your local machine has old/bad DNS data cached when you make a DNS change.

Quick test: try looking up the DNS record on your custom domain using

http://www.mydnstools.info/nslookup

If that looks correct, then google how to flush your DNS cache on whatever OS you are using.